# Android: Unable to update edittext with database values

Tags: android, android-edittext, achartengine

I have a table with 3 columns (name ,Avalue,Bvalue), i am creating a pie chart with A values using AchartEngine , now when i click the particular chart element i want to display both Avalue and Bvalue. I am able to get the AValue `using (seriesSelection.getValue())`since  the chart is creating with those value , how to get the Bvalue when particular chart element is clicked.

Below is my code

```
mChartView2=ChartFactory.getPieChartView(context, categorySeries,renderer);
              parent.addView(mChartView2);
              renderer.setClickEnabled(true);
              mChartView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                      SeriesSelection seriesSelection = mChartView2.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
                      if (seriesSelection == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No chart element selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                      }else {

                          TextView productname = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.productname);
                          productname.setText(categorySeries.getCategory(0));
                          for (int i = 0; i < categorySeries.getItemCount(); i++) {
                              renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).setHighlighted(i == seriesSelection.getPointIndex());


                          EditText Avalue = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.actualValue);
                          Avalue .setText(""+seriesSelection.getValue());

                          EditText Bvalue = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.budgetvalue);
                              budgetlval.setText(""+cursor2.getInt(2));

                          }
                          mChartView2.repaint();
                          }

                        }
                      });
              cursor1.close();
              return ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(context, categorySeries, renderer,null);
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SeriesSelection` provides you the series index and the point index as well. Use these in order to get the other values from your model.